# Remove Responsive Style of wp template

Tags: wordpress, viewport, responsive

I use a responsive template for my WordPress website.
I now need to remove responsive style for all display types (such as desktop).
I removed

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the header tag, but this didn't work; the site still shows responsive.

Comment: Sorted the jumble of phrases into meaningful sentences; I hope I got it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags alone won't really do the trick - you actually need to edit CSS and remove all styles related to the non-desktop versions of the theme.

Sometimes CSS may actually be written with "mobile first" approach, in this case you do not remove styles, but rather remove restrictions on screen sizes those are applied to (@media { .. } blocks).

If would consider creating a child theme and replacing CSS with own versions...

P.S. why would you remove responsiveness in the first place? It's there for a reason.

Comment: my all device user use of my website app

Answer (score 0):

i understandn't it
Sometimes CSS may actually be written with "mobile first" approach, in this case you do not remove styles, but rather remove restrictions on screen sizes those are applied to (@media { .. } blocks).